# Cant launch new coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I already have a lifecycleScope created in the MainActivity.
[image: class MainActivity]
When I try to create a new lifecycleScope, I get an error:
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public val LifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope defined in androidx.lifecycle
[image: class UniversityDetails]

I don't know what to try.

Comment: UniversityDetails isn't AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code snippet, you have:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

In your second code snippet, you have:

```kotlin
class UniversityDetails : Activity()
```

That is the source of your difficulty. Change the second code snippet to be:

```kotlin
class UniversityDetails : AppCompatActivity()
```

`lifecycleScope` is an extension property of `LifecycleOwner`. `Activity` does not implement `LifecycleOwner`, but `AppCompatActivity` does.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to read the documentation